# Using ZeroMQ with Visual Studio 2008 - LNK2019 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, zeromq

I need to use ZeroMQ in a an application built in Visual Studio 2008.  I've done the following:

-Download ZeroMQ to get the following library: libzmq-v90-mt-4_0_4.lib.

-Cloned the libzmq repository from Github.

-In Visual Studio project properties: Added the '\include' directory of the libzmq to C/C++->Include Addition Directories, added the libzmq-v90-mt-4_0_4.lib to the Linker->Input->Addition Dependencies, added the library directory to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.

I have both 'zmq.hpp' and 'zmq.h' in the '\include' directory, I've read opposing things about which one I should be referencing.  I've also read some about ZMQ_STATIC needing to be defined but that hasn't resolved the linker issue.  Any advice would be appreciated!

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "snoopygs.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");
    //    Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        zmq::message_t request (5);
        memcpy (request.data (), "Hello", 5);
        std::cout << "Sending Hello " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send (request);
        //  Get the reply.
        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv (&reply);
        std::cout << "Received World " << request_nbr << std::endl;
    }   

QApplication a(argc, argv);
SnoopyGS w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

These are 2 examples of the linking errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::message_t::message_t(void)" (??0message_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_errno referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::error_t::error_t(void)" (??0error_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: It may happen in MS VS if threading settings are different in library and project